# Cannot find previous inserted element in jquery ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code doesn't work, it seems the previous inserted element cannot be found by later script.

i updated basic syntax errors as the first three answners, but it seems still doesn't work.

code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready( function() {
     $('#menu').html('<a href="page4.html" class="dynamicLoad">ddd</a>');
 });  

$(document).ready( function() {
        $( 'a.dynamicLoad' ).click( function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();   // prevent the browser from following the link
            e.stopPropagation();  // prevent the browser from following the link
            $( '#myDiv' ).load( $( this ).attr( 'href' ) );
        });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>


<div id="menu">mymenu</div>
<div id="myDiv">aaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: – user125697, cannot find your answer.

Comment: thanks user125679, after fixing basic syntax issue, currently can find link element, but another issue is :
the load page cannot shown in div #myDiv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `innerHTML` statement to the following:

```
$('#menu').html("<a href='page4.html' class='dynamicLoad'>ddd</a>");
});
```

As currently your statement has multiple syntax errors.

Also, **[innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)** is Javascript **not** jQuery - [**html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is it's jQuery equivalent.

---

Here's a working [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZAK3f/).

Your whole code should now look like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menu">mymenu</div>
<div id="myDiv">aaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
     $('#menu').html("<a href='page4.html' class='dynamicLoad'>ddd</a>");
     $( 'a.dynamicLoad' ).click( function( e ) {
           e.preventDefault();   // prevent the browser from following the link
           e.stopPropagation();  // prevent the browser from following the link
           $( '#myDiv' ).load( $( this ).attr( 'href' ) );
     });
});
```

Comment: Be careful about (read: avoid) using w3schools links - [here's why](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: div html cannot be one html ? still cannot see the linked page

Comment: or how can i get the load page's body ? and then set the body to div?

Answer (score 0):

it should be `html()`

`innerHTML` == `html()`  in jquery

and escape your `"`

```
 $('#menu').html("<a href='page4.html' class='dynamicLoad'>ddd</a>");
   //------^^^^---here
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a quotes `"` issue and use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead:

```
$('#menu').html('<a href="page4.html" class="dynamicLoad">ddd</a>');
```

You should use `.html()` method of jQuery not `innerHTML` because jQuery is simplified some javascript functions. jQuery is still javascript but it has different and some simplified syntax.

Answer (score 0):

tyr this

```
$('#menu').html("<a href='page4.html' class='dynamicLoad'>ddd</a>");
```